# The correct position of brackets when calling a function within a higher order function

Tags: javascript

Let's say I want to print a console.log string 5 times using my own higher order function.

This works:

```
const sayHello = () => {
console.log("Hello") }

const sayHelloFiveTimes = (func) => {
    for (let i = 0; i<5; i++) {
        func() }}

sayHelloFiveTimes(sayHello)
```

Whereas this version console.logs the string one time only:

```
const sayHello = () => {
console.log("Hello") }

const sayHelloFiveTimes = (func) => {
    for (let i = 0; i<5; i++) {
        func }}

sayHelloFiveTimes(sayHello())
```

All that is different is brackets being removed from 'func' and added to 'sayHello'.

Can anybody please explain the logic to me of why this happens? What exactly is the computer processing for this to happen? Does 'sayHello()' not go in place of 'func'? Why does it not execute the function 5 times? Why does it execute the function at all?

Comment: Did you expect changing what was called where _wouldn't_ change the behaviour? In the second case what you call `func` is **not** a function, it's the (`undefined`) result of calling `sayHello`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is called wherever you put `()` after it.

So in the first version, it's called when it executes `func()`, which is inside the loop, so it's called 5 times.

In the second version it's called when it executes `sayHello()` in the argument list. So it's called just once, and the return value is passed to the `sayHelloFiveTimes()` function.

```
sayHelloFiveTimes(sayHello());
```

is equivalent to:

```
let temp = sayHello());
sayHelloFiveTimes(temp);
```

This makes it clearer that you're not passing a function reference, you're passing the result.

Furthermore, writing just `func` by itself in the loop doesn't do anything. It evaluates the value of `func`, but doesn't call it as a function (but since it's not a function, there's nothing to call).

Comment: Perfect explained thank you. I thought that the sayHello() function would literally get passed to func, as in literally replace func, and then only executed when sayHelloFiveTimes() was parsed. What I was missing is that sayHello() is executed before it ever executes sayHelloFiveTimes(), so all func becomes is the return value of sayHello(), which in this example, is none. Makes so much sense now, thanks so much.